# ORA-00905: missing keyword error in case after where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, case, where-clause, toad

I have the following query which is giving error `ORA-00905: missing keyword`. I've not been able to find the syntax despite continuous efforts for last few hours. Please help.

```
SELECT a.DOCUMENT_CATEGORY,
         a.template_id,
         a.category_id,
         a.REVIEW_CATEGORY,
         a.WITH_BIDS,
         a.WITH_FINAL_DOCUMENTS,
         b.divn_id,
         b.deptt_id,
         a.vdr_id,
         C.DEPARTMENT,
         a.TEMPLATE_TITLE
    FROM DCTM_VDR_REF_DTLS a, DCTM_VDR_REF_MASTER b, VW_DIVN_DIR c
   WHERE     b.DIVN_ID = c.DIVN_CODE
         AND b.DEPTT_ID = c.SECTN_CODE
         AND a.vdr_id = b.vdr_id
         AND (b.REFERENCE_NUMBER, b.APPROVED_ON) IN
                (  SELECT MAX (REFERENCE_NUMBER), MAX (APPROVED_ON)
                     FROM DCTM_VDR_REF_MASTER
                    WHERE     REFERENCE_NUMBER =
                                 (SELECT DISTINCT
                                         NVL (TRIM (MR_NUMBER), TRIM (TENDER_NO))
                                    FROM EILEDMS.EIL_DOCUMENT_SV@EDMS_DBLINK
                                   WHERE     object_name =
                                                'A307-0IC-JA-MR-7960-1030-157-FOA'
                                         AND r_object_type =
                                                'eil_foa_order_pr_doc'
                                         AND (   title = 'FOA'
                                              OR title = 'DRAFT FOA'))
                          AND APPROVED_ON IS NOT NULL
                 GROUP BY DIVN_ID, DEPTT_ID)
         AND REVIEW_CATEGORY <> 'Delete Category'
         AND (CASE (SELECT IS_SCHEDULE_LOCKED
                      FROM DCTM_VENDOR_SCHEDULE
                     WHERE SCH_ID = 359)
                 WHEN 0
                 THEN
                    1
                 WHEN 1
                 THEN
                    (a.template_id || '-' || a.category_id) IN
                       (SELECT template_id || '-' || category_id
                          FROM DCTM_VENDOR_SCH_UNLOCK_DTLS
                         WHERE     APPROVAL = 'Y'
                               AND APPROVAL_UPTO >= SYSDATE
                               AND CONSUMED = 0
                               AND sch_ID = 359)
              END) = 1
ORDER BY c.DEPARTMENT ASC,
         a.TEMPLATE_ID,
         a.SORT_ORDER,
         a.DOCUMENT_CATEGORY ASC
```

**Can't we use IN clause inside a THEN statement?**

Comment: The last WHEN 1 THEN statement in the CASE doesn't makes sense at all and is the cause of the problem.

Comment: Can't we include an IN clause inside a THEN statment?

Comment: To elaborate on @tvm, you have a clause which is basically `WHEN value THEN boolean` which isn't allowed in Oracle. You'll need to turn the boolean into a SQL-supported datatype, and probably the value 0 or 1 in this particular case.

Comment: What are you expecting that `IN` clause to do? You're specifying a value the `case when 1` clause should evaluate to, so it needs to return a single value. You have some a fixed value and then.... `IN` which has no meaning here, and another select, which makes no sense. You also seem to be expecting the whole `case` to compare to a number value, but this `when` is a string (or perhaps multiple strings, which also won't work). You need to figure out what you're trying to do here, I think.

Comment: @Colin'tHart How should I convert that expression contatining IN operator for it to return a number value? Should I use some function like DECODE?

Comment: @AlexPoole I want that if the case expression return 0, there should not be any filter but when it returns 1, the rsult set should be filtered according to the expression containing IN operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that you've edited your question, it looks like you are simply trying to look up category_id and template_id in DCTM_VENDOR_SCH_UNLOCK_DTLS. Does the following work for you?

```
then 
(
  SELECT COUNT(*) -- 1 if found, 0 otherwise
    FROM DCTM_VENDOR_SCH_UNLOCK_DTLS
   WHERE     APPROVAL = 'Y'
         AND APPROVAL_UPTO >= SYSDATE
         AND CONSUMED = 0
         AND sch_ID = 359
         AND template_id = a.template_id
         AND category_id = a.category_id
         AND rownum = 1
)
```

Comment: It worked Thorsten. Thanks. though I am still trying to understand the logic behind it. :p

Answer (score 0):

This is not actually about an IN clause after WHERE being allowed or not. The expression

```
a.category_id IN (SELECT ...)
```

evaluates to TRUE or FALSE. Your statement

```
a.template_id || '-' || a.category_id IN (SELECT ...)
```

tries to concatenate that TRUE or FALSE with a.template_id and a minus sign. This is not possible, as there is no boolean type in Oracle SQL. Think it over what you actually want to concatenate.

EDIT: Now that you set parentheses, you compare a string with another string resulting from a select statement. Fine so far. But still: All this evaluates to a boolean, not a number. Your first then results in a number (1), your second in a boolean (TRUE or FALSE). Oracle SQL has no boolean type, so your expression makes no sense to the parser and you get a syntax error.

Comment: Having said this, the expression "a.template_id || '-' || whatever" will also never evaluate to 1, which is what you compare the case result with.

Comment: Woderful observation Thorsten. But I think the precedence of operators is setting it right because even after putting parenthesis around "a.template_id || '-' || a.category_id", I am getting the same error "Missing keyword".

Comment: No, sorry, you have misunderstood completely. The quotes where only to separate the expression from the rest of the sentence. What I am saying is: you have a case statement with two then clauses. The first is "then 1". The second should be something like "then 2" or whatever, but instead it is a string consisting of an id a minus sign and a boolean (which does not work, as explained in my answer). So let this evaluate to '123-XXX' or '1-TRUE' or '1-', ... whatever this string will never ever be 1. But this is what you compare your case result with in "END) = 1".

Comment: Thorsten, I have edited the code above. Please notice the parenthesis around "a.template_id || '-' || a.category_id". I think this tends to your objection, but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: That clarifies things, but still you are dealing with a boolean result here, which you cannot do. (See my edited answer.)

Comment: I've added another answer that should solve the problem for you.